# NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://h.online-metrix.net/fp/clear.png?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing a IOS app and while reviewing the console messages I saw the following message coming from my app.

---

NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://h.online-metrix.net/fp/clear.png?org_id=xxxx&session_id=xxx

NSLocalizedDescription = "The request timed out.";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 \"The request timed out.

---

My question is what is this and what are they trying to do? I searched on google and it seems to be owned by a security technology company called ThreatMetrix.  This message came from my app, but I don't remember having anything  to do with them.  Searched my code and can't seem to figure out where this is coming from.

Comment: Are you using iAd? Are you using any third party, non-open source libraries?

Comment: Sounds like some Data Analytics library trying to make a request back to their server but failing.

Comment: I am using chartboost, revmob, tapjoy, localytics and bug sense. I know that many libraries use this to check if internet is reachable but they typically use google/apple. Not sure why this site is being used and was getting worried if this is a malware